# how to populate data to table when enter data and click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build an html with multiples page to add and view events using jquery mobile.

1. I have a table which contains date and subject of event(data should get updated when user add a event)
2. when click on add event button a page with subject and details appear after entering data and clicks on add,data is not getting
   updated to table i.e to step 1
3. when select an added event(from step 1 table) and click on view event the subject and details of event should get displayed.

I am new to jquery mobile. Can anyone help me out?
Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Event Planning</h1>
            </div>
        <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <a href="#addevent">Add Event</a><br>
                <a href="#viewevent">View Event</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add event page-->
        <div data-role="page" id="addevent">
        <section data-role="content">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="note_subject">
        <label for="details">Details</label>
        <textarea name="details" id="note_text"></textarea> 
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="add">
        </section>
        </div>
        <!-- View event page-->
        <div data-role="page" id="viewevent">
        </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the javascript. It is up to you to provide your attempts to solve your problem with code

Comment: Here is my JS fiddle and I am using jquery mobile http://jsfiddle.net/Priya16/RTuJX/1/

Comment: Is that code your own or copied (and ev. adapted) from somewhere? Do you know how localStorage and JSON work in your fiddle? Have you checked your dependencies? In the fiddle, the call to all your `jquery-mobile` libraries fail for me. So it's obviously not going to work if jquery mobile isn't loaded...

Comment: its my own code,i am using the local storage and Json to store array of events to the local storage and want that to populate into the table when clicks on add button